# Cannot click on Login using Appium ,Can click manually

Tags: python, xcode, ios-simulator, appium

```
Appium 1.5.0
Xcode  7.3
IOS 10.11.4 OSX EI Capitan
Using on:Simulator iOS 8.1
```

Facing a strange issue.I can click via touchpad but not through Appium .

**Appium Logs:**

```
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:54 +0000 Debug: Got new command 14 from instruments: au.tapById('3')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:54 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.tapById('3')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:54 +0000 Debug: UIAButton.tap()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:54 +0000 Debug: UIAButton.scrollToVisible()
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:54 Macbook.local securityd[29291]:  SecTaskCopyAccessGroups No keychain access group specified whilst running in simulator, falling back to default set
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:54 Macbook.local TT Mobile[29305]: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:54 Macbook.local securityd[29291]:  SecTaskCopyAccessGroups No keychain access group specified whilst running in simulator, falling back to default set
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:54 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:54 +0000 Debug: responding with:
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:54 +0000 Debug: Running system command #15: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js /var/folders/4x/vy1bbyh92l9czkyswl5wypt80000gn/T/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (25 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.click() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/3957fc67-82da-4e57-b920-005ee0228cd7/element/3/click 200 1231 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/3957fc67-82da-4e57-b920-005ee0228cd7/element 
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","LOG IN","3957fc67-82da-4e57-b920-005ee0228cd7"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'findElement'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 60000 ms for condition
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementByAccessibilityId('LOG IN')
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:55 Macbook.local lsd[29289]: LaunchServices: Currently 0 installed placeholders: (
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] )
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:55 +0000 Debug: Got new command 15 from instruments: au.getElementByAccessibilityId('LOG IN')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:55 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElementByAccessibilityId('LOG IN')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:55 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:55 +0000 Debug: Lookup returned [object UIAButton] with the name "LOG IN" (id: 4).
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:55 +0000 Debug: responding with:
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:55 +0000 Debug: Running system command #16: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js /var/folders/4x/vy1bbyh92l9czkyswl5wypt80000gn/T/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"}}...
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (38 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"}}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"4"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/3957fc67-82da-4e57-b920-005ee0228cd7/element 200 1344 ms - 87 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/3957fc67-82da-4e57-b920-005ee0228cd7/element/4/click 
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args: ["4","3957fc67-82da-4e57-b920-005ee0228cd7"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'click'
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: au.tapById('4')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:56 +0000 Debug: Got new command 16 from instruments: au.tapById('4')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:56 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.tapById('4')
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:56 +0000 Debug: UIAButton.tap()
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:57 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:57 +0000 Debug: responding with:
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] 2016-04-19 04:30:57 +0000 Debug: Running system command #17: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js /var/folders/4x/vy1bbyh92l9czkyswl5wypt80000gn/T/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (25 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.click() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/3957fc67-82da-4e57-b920-005ee0228cd7/element/4/click 200 1164 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/3957fc67-82da-4e57-b920-005ee0228cd7/element
```

**XML of the App**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AppiumAUT>
        <UIAApplication name="TT Mobile α" label="TT Mobile α" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0" x="0" y="20" width="320" height="548">
            <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
                <UIAImage name="bg-login" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
                </UIAImage>
                <UIATextField name="" label="" value="Email address" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/1" x="27.5" y="178" width="265" height="40">
                    <UIATextField name="" label="" value="Email address" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/1/0" x="27.5" y="178" width="265" height="40">
                    </UIATextField>
                </UIATextField>
                <UIASecureTextField name="" label="" value="Password" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/2" x="27.5" y="218" width="265" height="40">
                    <UIASecureTextField name="" label="" value="Password" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/2/0" x="27.5" y="218" width="265" height="40">
                    </UIASecureTextField>
                </UIASecureTextField>
                <UIAButton name="unchecked" label="unchecked" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/3" x="27.5" y="280" width="28" height="25.5">
                </UIAButton>
                <UIAStaticText name="Remember me" label="Remember me" value="Remember me" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/4" x="59.5" y="282.5" width="110" height="21">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAButton name="forgot password?" label="forgot password?" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/5" x="186.5" y="282.5" width="106" height="21">
                </UIAButton>
                <UIAButton name="LOG IN" label="LOG IN" value="" dom="" enabled="false" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/6" x="27.5" y="341" width="265" height="43">
                </UIAButton>
                <UIAActivityIndicator name="In progress" label="In progress" value="1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/7" x="150" y="352.5" width="20" height="20">
                    <UIAImage name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/7/0" x="150" y="352.5" width="20" height="20">
                    </UIAImage>
                </UIAActivityIndicator>
                <UIAStaticText name="Don&apos;t have an ID?" label="Don&apos;t have an ID?" value="Don&apos;t have an ID?" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/8" x="27.5" y="396" width="151" height="24">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAButton name="Sign Up" label="Sign Up" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/9" x="183.5" y="396.5" width="78" height="23.5">
                </UIAButton>
                <UIAButton name="Demo" label="Demo" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/10" x="27.5" y="485" width="265" height="33">
                </UIAButton>
                <UIAImage name="login-ttmobile" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/11" x="34" y="71" width="252" height="34">
                </UIAImage>
                <UIAStaticText name="TWO-FACTOR AUTHENTICATION" label="TWO-FACTOR AUTHENTICATION" value="TWO-FACTOR AUTHENTICATION" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/12" x="28" y="154" width="264" height="21">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIASecureTextField name="" label="" value="Enter code" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/13" x="27.5" y="250" width="265" height="40">
                    <UIASecureTextField name="" label="" value="Enter code" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/13/0" x="27.5" y="250" width="265" height="40">
                    </UIASecureTextField>
                </UIASecureTextField>
                <UIAButton name="VERIFY" label="VERIFY" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/14" x="27.5" y="314" width="265" height="43">
                    <UIAStaticText name="VERIFY" label="VERIFY" value="VERIFY" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/14/0" x="125.5" y="321" width="68" height="29">
                    </UIAStaticText>
                </UIAButton>
                <UIAActivityIndicator name="In progress" label="In progress" value="1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/15" x="150" y="325.5" width="20" height="20">
                </UIAActivityIndicator>
                <UIAButton name="unchecked" label="unchecked" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/16" x="27.5" y="372" width="28" height="25.5">
                    <UIAImage name="unchecked.png" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/16/0" x="29" y="373.5" width="24.5" height="22">
                    </UIAImage>
                </UIAButton>
                <UIAStaticText name="Remember device for 30 days" label="Remember device for 30 days" value="Remember device for 30 days" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/17" x="59.5" y="374.5" width="233" height="21">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAButton name="BACK" label="BACK" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/18" x="27.5" y="445.5" width="102" height="30">
                    <UIAImage name="icon-swipeleft.png" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/18/0" x="27.5" y="452.5" width="9.5" height="15.5">
                    </UIAImage>
                    <UIAStaticText name="BACK" label="BACK" value="BACK" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/18/1" x="44" y="451.5" width="35" height="18">
                    </UIAStaticText>
                </UIAButton>
                <UIAButton name="request new code" label="request new code" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/19" x="186.5" y="450" width="106" height="21">
                    <UIAStaticText name="request new code" label="request new code" value="request new code" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/19/0" x="187.5" y="451" width="105" height="18">
                    </UIAStaticText>
                </UIAButton>
            </UIAWindow>
            <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
                <UIAStatusBar name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="20">
                    <UIAElement name="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/0" x="6" y="0" width="38" height="20">
                    </UIAElement>
                    <UIAElement name="3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars" label="3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/1" x="49" y="0" width="13" height="20">
                    </UIAElement>
                    <UIAElement name="10:19 AM" label="10:19 AM" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/2" x="135" y="0" width="50" height="20">
                    </UIAElement>
                    <UIAElement name="100% battery power" label="100% battery power" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/1/0/3" x="290" y="0" width="25" height="20">
                    </UIAElement>
                </UIAStatusBar>
            </UIAWindow>
        </UIAApplication>
    </AppiumAUT>
```

**Some logs which i could not decipher:**

```
[IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:40 Macbook com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.55BBCE9D-8F75-47DC-BC87-3DD28FB4F874.launchd_sim[29262] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.

[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:41 Macbook.local filecoordinationd[29326]: (Error) FileProvider: Could not load bundle com.apple.CloudDocsFileProvider. Error: The bundle “CloudDocsFileProvider” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.

[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:54 Macbook.local securityd[29291]:  SecTaskCopyAccessGroups No keychain access group specified whilst running in simulator, falling back to default set
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:54 Macbook.local TT Mobile[29305]: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Apr 19 10:00:54 Macbook.local securityd[29291]:  SecTaskCopyAccessGroups No keychain access group specified whilst running in simulator, falling back to default set
```

Any clues or help?

Build created using xcode for arch i386

Comment: What is the Xpath locator you are using to locate the button in Appium?

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks m using `by_id`....`LOG IN`..i guess element is getting detected.....

Comment: I have had trouble with `By.id("LOG IN")`, so I recommend to use `By.xpath("//UIAButton[@name='LOG IN']")`.

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks didnt work....can you see the logs of IOS...as i fear there might be some issue with the build it self....as i sometimes cannot click manually after running appium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `set_value` on ios for `password` which does not use `keyboard`.The `LOG IN` button is disabled until there is some text in `password` field.So somehow `set_value` was not generating the event.Problem solved by using `send_keys` which uses `keyboard`.